# Vim expands percent sign '%' in URL

Tags: vimscript

In my script, I am trying to open an URL in my default browser using

```
silent exec '!rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler '.a:url
```

where `a:url` is an URL-encoded string containing percent `%` signs.
Vim obviously expands the percent sign with the current file name, resulting in an URL like

`https://slovnik.seznam.cz/preklad/cesky_nemecky/bohatmyFile.txtc3myFile.txtbd`

instead of

`https://slovnik.seznam.cz/preklad/cesky_nemecky/bohat%c3%bd`

*(Remark: The encoded string stands for "bohatý" - "rich" in Czech)*

How can I prevent VIM from expanding the percent sign?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`escape()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#escape%28%29) function to escape characters that are interpreted as meta-characters, such as `%` (also `#` and `!` in the case of running an external command with `:!`.)

In your case:

```
silent exec '!rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler '.escape(a:url, '%#!')
```

One alternative, particularly as you're using `silent`, so not interested in the command's output, is to use the [`system()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) function call directly, which doesn't do as much command-line mangling as `:!` does.

```
call system('rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler '.a:url)
```

One advantage of `system()` (or [`systemlist()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#systemlist%28%29)) is that you *can* get the output of the commands as a Vimscript string (or list of lines), if you wish to inspect or manipulate them after the command has finished running.

Comment: Thank you, the `escape()` function solved the problem. `system()` did not work, though. The browser did not open.